# Split Date Wed Jan 27 2016 02:14:05 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)

Tags: javascript

I have this date (Wed Jan 27 2016 02:14:05 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
and I want to split it in order to take only the hours (02:14:05).
How i can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date('Wed Jan 27 2016 02:14:05 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)');
var time = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
  ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
  ('0' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert it to date object and use `date.toTimeString()` or `date.toLocaleTimeString()`

```js
var date = new Date("Wed Jan 27 2016 02:14:05 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)");

console.log(date.toTimeString());
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString());
```

Answer (score 0):

using javascript regex

```
var str = "Wed Jan 27 2016 02:14:05 GMT+0200"; 
var regex = /[\d\d]*:[\d\d]*:[\d\d]*/;
var res = str.match(regex);
```